# NSLeftTextAlignment with spaces at end of string

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

if I sets NSCenterTextAlignment for my NSTextView
my whitespaces at the end of string magically disappears

for example I have string

```
@"while      "
```

if I display it with NSRightTextAlignment it shows well

```
|white      |
```

but with NSLeftTextAlignment all whitespaces just cut

```
|white|
```

how can I get results like

```
|      white|
```

tabs is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: it sounds as if you are trying to left-align centered items by using spaces to pad some of them. If you must do this you can use non-breaking spaces (UTF-16 0x00A0, type as option-space). HTH